# Webdriver JS - Failed to load extension from.. Manifest file is missing or unreadable

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to load an extension into chrome using webdriver js. I have the .CRX file / Unpacked / Zip in path defined. but to no avail. All files are in same location

I receive a popup stating *Failed to load extension from C:\Program Files(x86)\ Google\Chrome\Application\80.0.3987.87\ C:\SeleniumJS\Ext\extension_2_41_0.CRX. Manifest file is missing or unreadable.*

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var path = "C:\\SeleniumJS\\Ext\\extension_2_4_1_0\\";

options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("enable-automation");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments( `--load-extension= ${path}` );

const builder = new webdriver.Builder();
builder.setChromeOptions(options);
const driver = builder.forBrowser( 'chrome' ).build();
driver.get ('http://www.bbc.co.uk');
```

Comment: Unpack the extension to a directory and specify it in `path`. Also remove `, ` after --load-extension.

Comment: I have attempted an unpacked , ie the folder contents etc. Its in the same location in path also. unless you think the path is wrong. All files are in C:\SeleniumJS\Ext\

Comment: Updated above in original post.

Comment: There's still an extra space after `=` and I would try without the trailing `\\`.

Comment: Thanks pal, Thats worked. extra space Grrr.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your files is not in a subfolderand the folder is direcltly on the drive for example D:\your folder (that containes the extension files)